# Convert CFIndex to NSUInteger?

Tags: objective-c, c, typedef, core-foundation, foundation

How do I convert `typedef signed long CFIndex` to `typedef unsigned int NSUInteger`?

Is it OK if I use a `CFIndex` as an argument of type `NSUInteger`. I haven't casted it, and the complier doesn't seem to mind. Does the compiler just do the conversion for me?

Answer (score 5):

You need to be very careful here, since CFIndex is signed and NSUInteger is unsigned. There are various routines that return a CFIndex -1. You need to check for that before using it as an NSUInteger.

Comment: if (index >= 0) { NSUInteger uIndex = (NSUInteger)index; ... } else { error-or-return-or-whatever; }

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the compiler performs [implicit type conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion).