# Converting CFIndex to NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion, core-foundation, nsinteger, toll-free-bridging

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952738/convert-cfindex-to-nsuinteger) question is similar to mine, but does not contain an answer. I want to convert a `CFIndex` into an `NSInteger`. I have checked the list of types that have toll-free bridging and this is not one of them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The concept of toll-free bridging only applies to Objective-C objects and Core Foundation objects.  `CFIndex` is simply a typedef for the primitive `signed long` type, and `NSInteger` is a typedef for the primitive `long` type, which is the same as `signed long`.  You can just assign a value of one type to a variable of the other type.